# Pgfplots dynamic opacity

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to add multiple plots on one axis and I would like them to have different opacities (e.g. 0.1, 0.2 etc.). I have tried with different options:

1. The only thing that actually compiles is foreach with count variable. What it doesn't do is change the opacity of the plots:

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \begin{document}
       \begin{tikzpicture}
           \begin{axis}[width=0.8\textwidth]
               \foreach [count=\op] \x in{1,...,10} {
               \addplot[thick, color=blue, opacity={0.1*\op}] table[x index = 0, y index = \op, col sep=tab]{data.csv};
               }
           \end{axis}
       \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. pgfmathsetmacro, doesn't compile:

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \begin{document}
       \begin{tikzpicture}
           \begin{axis}[width=0.8\textwidth]
               \foreach \x in{1,...,10} {
               \pgfmathsetmacro\op{\x*0.1}
               \addplot[thick, color=blue, opacity={\op}] table[x index = 0, y index = \x, col sep=tab]{data.csv};
               }
           \end{axis}
       \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```
3. Using evaluate, doesn't compile:

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \begin{document}
       \begin{tikzpicture}
           \begin{axis}[width=0.8\textwidth]
                 \foreach [evaluate=\x as \op using {0.1*\x}] \x in{1,...,10} {
                 \addplot[thick, color=blue, opacity={\op}] table[x index = 0, y index = \x, col sep=tab]{data.csv};
                 }
           \end{axis}
       \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```

I am sure there is a possibility it's just that I have not had too much experience with pgfplots yet and am probably missing something obvious.

Data file can be accessed here: [data.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a6mc48rghgn2id9/data.csv)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For applications like this, you need to use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` instead of the normal `\foreach` loop. The issue with the normal `\foreach` is that PGFPlots first collects all the `\addplot` commands generated within your loop and executes them at a later point, when the variable `\op` is set to `1` for all the plots. `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` makes sure that the value of the loop variable is stored with the `\addplot` command.

To get your example to work, use the following syntax (note that you have to use `#1` instead of a named macro for the loop variable):

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,10} {
            \addplot[thick, color=blue, opacity={0.1*#1}] table ...
}
```

[image]